# Alfresco DotCMIS CommunicationException on getContentStream()

Tags: alfresco, dotcms

When trying to download a 4mb file using DotCMIS (WebServices binding), I receive the following exception when trying to get the content stream of the file.

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (4194304) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

I tried modifying app/web configs to no avail. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Switch to using AtomPub or Browser bindings?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, work at Alfresco? Because that answer is something I would have expected to hear from them. Oh, wait, no. What I would have expected from them is absolute silence. 

Pardon me for being sarcastic, this whole thing irked me beyond any reason. We actually switched from AtomPub to webservices (and experienced excruciating amounts of pain while doing that), because some features (like copying documents) don't work through AtomPub.

Comment: Many years ago I did! And a number of current and former Alfrescans can be found here on StackOverflow, helping out, in addition to Alfresco's support team on the phone / via tickets. General CMIS advice though is that Browser Binding is the fastest, then AtomPub, and avoid WebServices if you can!

Comment: Switching stuff is not a good idea in a large project, especially when you can't just switch binding type in session parameters and expect it to work.

Browser binding is not implemented in DotCMIS, Atompub does not support copying and I can't say that WebServices perform noticeably worse than AtomPub where they don't perform better (thanks to copying). Luckily enough I noticed that one parameter, so all is well. For now. Until we hit something else that is stupidly simple but mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure DotCMIS is getting much work these days. Most of the .Net effort is going into a new PortCMIS codebase, see [CMIS-926](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-926) (someone seems to have forgotten to update the website...)

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of playing with app.configs, downloading and studying sources and hopeless googling, the solution turned out to be, as always, painfully simple, obvious and not mentioned anywhere. Or maybe it's just that my googling skills are that of an underage imbecile with alzheimers. That lacks a brain. I'm not sure anymore.

As for the solution: SessionParameters static class / enum thingie has a wonderful field, called "**MessageSize**". Which defaults to **4194304**. Setting it sets MaxReceivedMessageSize.